# Realm object changed, another copy of that object has changed too, why?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am stuck in a problem. Let's assume I have this Realm Model:

```
class Table: Object {
    dynamic var id = 0
    dynamic var x: Int = 0
    dynamic var y: Int = 0
    dynamic var width:Int = 0
    dynamic var height: Int = 0
    dynamic var text: String = ""
    dynamic var color: String = ""
    dynamic var type: String = ""

    let food = List<Food>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "id"
    }
}

class Food : Object {

    dynamic var id: Int = 0
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var ingredients: String = "" // bigger text field
    dynamic var size: Int = 0 // none, small, medium, big size
    dynamic var price: Float = 0.0
    dynamic var category: Category?
    let additionalIngredients = List<Ingredient>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

Let's say I have one table and added 2 times the same food on that table like so :

```
try! realm.write(){
    table.food.append(food) // A
    table.food.append(food) // B
    realm.add(table, update: true)
}
```

If I change the additionalIngredients for food A , also at the same food B changes its values. I am doing that changes with this transaction :

```
try! realm.write(){
    table.food.first!.additionalIngredients.removeAll()
    for ingredient in ingredientsToAdd{
        table.food.first!.additionalIngredients.append(ingredient)
    }
    realm.add(table, update: true)
}
```

I guess I am doing something wrong regarding the reference/instance, can someone give me a hint?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think it occurs because food_A and food_B refer to the same object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`List.append()` adds the object itself to the list and not a copy of the object, so you only have one `Food` object.

Comment: So how can I add a copy of that food object to a table  and manipulate it? Is that even possible with Realm?

Comment: @MkaysWork in your case you have a primary key for your model, so you have to change it for the new copy, this issue https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1910 could be helpful

Comment: Thought about it again and you are right @Dmitry. Thank you!